# Multiline text extraction in R with stringr

Tags: r

I have a column in my dataframe which has free text in it

I would like to extract the text after `INDICATIONS FOR EXAMINATION` and before the next capitalized line. In the example below the result would be 'Anaemia'

```
INDICATIONS FOR EXAMINATION
Anaemia

PROCEDURE PERFORMED
Gastroscopy (OGD)
```

I am having some trouble as I'm using `stringr` and I can't seem to get multiline matches.
I have been using:

```
EoE$IndicationsFroExamination<-str_extract(EoE$Endo_ResultText, '(?<=INDICATIONS FOR EXAMINATION).*?[A-Z]+')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires a little digging. You can use the `regex()` modifier function.

1. Use the `multiline` argument to switch on multiline fitting:

```
str_extract_all("a\nb\nc", "^.")
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"

str_extract_all("a\nb\nc", regex("^.", multiline = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

2. Please be aware of the `dotall` argument, that will switch on multiline behaviour of `".*"`:

```
str_extract_all("a\nb\nc", "a.")
# [[1]]
# character(0)

str_extract_all("a\nb\nc", regex("a.", dotall = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "a\n"
```

These are documented in [`stringi::stri_opts_regex()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.7.8/topics/stri_opts_regex), which `stringr::regex()` passes arguments to.

Answer (score 2):

I made the regular expression a bit more generic so it will match all occurrences and used the `str_extract_all` package from `stringr`:

```
matches <- str_extract_all(str, "(?<=[A-Z]\n)([^\n]*)")
```

Which, given the string you provided, should return:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Anaemia"           "Gastroscopy (OGD)"
```

Comment: I would like the match to stop before the next capitalised line which means it should only return 'Anaemia'

Comment: It's giving you each match. So: `matches[[1]][1]` would be `"Anaemia"` and `matches[[1]][2]` would be `"Gastroscopy (OGD)"`

If you only ever want the first, you can just use `matches <- str_extract(str, "(?<=[A-Z]\n)([^\n]*)")`